# There is a better way to translate the results of a query using yii2tech\spreadsheet\Spreadsheet

Tags: php, yii2, translation, spreadsheet

I'm doing a manual query. You can translate the names of the columns easily, but I can not do it with the results of the columns in a slightly more efficient way. The results are printed in excel with the help of `yii2tech\spreadsheet\Spreadsheet`.

**Preparing query**

```php
$columns = [
  [
    'attribute' => 'description',
    'label' => Yii::t('data', 'Description')
  ],
  [
    'attribute' => 'type',
    'label' => Yii::t('data', 'Type')
  ]
];

$query
  ->addSelect(['description' => 'data.description'])
  ->addSelect(['type' => 'data.type'])
  ->from('data')

$rows = $query->all();
```

So far I make the query. The following is my way of translating the results of the `type` column. Because they can be just some values.

**Translating results**

```php
foreach ($rows as $key => $row) {
  $rows[$key]['type'] = Yii::t('data', $row['type']);
}
```

This data is exported to xls format:

**Exporting results**

```php
$exporter = new Spreadsheet([
  'dataProvider' => new ArrayDataProvider([
    'allModels' => $rows,
  ]),
  'columns' => $columns,
]);
```

Comment: i seriously could not understand what you are trying to do the array you posted initially does not have any column named `type` where as the result set you receive from the query you add `type` index to every row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may define translation inside of `$columns` declaration - it will save you manual iteration trough results array to replace type with translated string:

```
$columns = [
    [
        'attribute' => 'description',
        'label' => Yii::t('data', 'Description'),
    ],
    [
        'attribute' => 'type',
        'label' => Yii::t('data', 'Type'),
        'value' => function ($data) {
            return Yii::t('data', $data['type']);
        }
    ],
];
```

If sheet is big and types are often repeated, you may try to cache translated string - `Yii::t()` may be quite expensive:

```
$columns = [
    [
        'attribute' => 'description',
        'label' => Yii::t('data', 'Description'),
    ],
    [
        'attribute' => 'type',
        'label' => Yii::t('data', 'Type'),
        'value' => function ($data) {
            static $translations = [];
            if (!isset($translations[$data['type']])) {
                $translations[$data['type']] = Yii::t('data', $data['type']);
            }

            return $translations[$data['type']];
        },
    ],
];
```

This will call `Yii::t()` only once per unique type. But if list of types is small and hardcoded, you may simplify this even more - create `getTranslatedTypes()` static method, which returns translated list of all types:

```
public static function getTranslatedTypes() {
    return [
        'some type' => Yii::t('data', 'some type'),
        // ...
    ];
}
```

And use it as a source of translations:

```
$translations = Type::getTranslatedTypes();
$columns = [
    [
        'attribute' => 'description',
        'label' => Yii::t('data', 'Description'),
    ],
    [
        'attribute' => 'type',
        'label' => Yii::t('data', 'Type'),
        'value' => function ($data) use ($translations) {
            return $translations[$data['type']] ?? $data['type'];
        },
    ],
];
```